# How to use a segment to select a value then use that value in a formula

Tags: iphone

I am trying to simply have a segment when selected pick a factor and use it in a formula. The problem i am having is converting the factor  a (float) into a  value a (double) and show this on the display. What am I  doing wrong here?  Seems like an easy fix but I've tried a lot of things to no avail.

### .h

NSInteger segPicked, var1, var2;

### .m

var1 = 1100;
var2 = 2.5;

```
- (void) pickOne:(id)sender {   // Selector for twosegment controller
if (checkCondition == properCondition) {
    segUnit.text = [twoSegments titleForSegmentAtIndex: [SixSegments selectedSegmentIndex]];
     segPicked    = [twoSegments selectedSegmentIndex];
```

```
    float factor = 0;   

if (segPicked  == 0 ) {
    factor = 0.28;
    } else if (segPicked  == 1 ) {
          factor = 0.16; 
      }

    double  value = (factor*(var1/var2));     <--- It crashes here..
    Result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment with  = ", value];

}
```

}

Comment: Before crash, check what are the values of `var1, var2`. If it is garbage, it is obvious that it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that var2 must be != 0

and:

```
   Result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment with  = ", value];
```

should be:

```
   Result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment with  = %f", value];
```

**EDIT:**

```
float factor;
NSInteger var1;
NSInteger var2;

float var2_test;
var1 = 1100;
var2 = 2.5;
var2_test = 2.5;
NSLog(@"int var2: %i, float var2_test: %f", var2, var2_test); // var2=2

factor = 0.16;
double value;
value = (factor*(var1/var2));  //  Not Crashes to me!

NSLog(@"******: %f", value);
```

it all works good to me, no crashes, are you sure it crashes at that point?

just a consideration:

var2 = 2.5;
var2 is: 2 (it's an integer)

Comment: @ meronix Thanks.. I was presetting the vars to zero in the startup and never gave them value after that or checked for !=0. Silly me. Your right it works and Var2 is an integer which is fine i will just use a float value there. Thanks for your response. – user597753 10 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Division by Zero ?
Dividing two integers?

```
double  value = (factor*(var1/var2));
```